# Android layout isn't displayed correctly and scrollable

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I've done a `RelativeLayout` with few `buttons` and `textviews`, there are two areas with this `buttons` and `textviews`,between and under that there are two `expandable listview`. All this it's inside a `ScrollView`. It works but the last list goes out of the screen and i can't scroll down. I need help to fix my layout, what i have to do? I've tryed also to put some child layout but it doesn't work. 
What is the best way to develop what i'm trying to do?

That's my xml code. Thank's.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
         android:fillViewport="true"
        >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="460dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TALance"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ALance"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ALance"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ALance"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/attacco"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TASpade"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ASpade"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ASpade"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ASpade"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ACl"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ACp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TACl"
        android:background="@drawable/cl"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TACl"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ACl"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ACl"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TACp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TACp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ACp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ACp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ACp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/AArchi"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TACp"
        android:background="@drawable/cp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/AArchi"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ABalestre"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TABalestre"
        android:background="@drawable/archi"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ABalestre"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ASpade"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TABalestre"
        android:background="@drawable/balestre"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TAArchi"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/AArchi"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/AArchi"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TABalestre"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TABalestre"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ABalestre"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ABalestre"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ASpade"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ALance"
        android:background="@drawable/spade"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:divider="@drawable/line"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TASpade" >

    </ExpandableListView>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView04"
        android:divider="@drawable/line"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >

    </ExpandableListView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ALance"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="@drawable/lance"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TASpade"
        android:background="@drawable/lance"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView03"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ACl"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list"
        android:background="@drawable/cp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TAArchi"
        android:background="@drawable/balestre"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText02"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText03"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageView03"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView03"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView04"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:background="@drawable/spade"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText04"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageView04"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView04"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView05"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/EditText04"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ImageView02"
        android:background="@drawable/archi"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText05"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageView05"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EditText02"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView06"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/EditText05"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ImageView03"
        android:background="@drawable/cl"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText06"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageView06"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView06"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

That's how it looks like(i've covered the images):

[image]

Comment: remove all listview and ExpandableListView under the scrollview. may be it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your relative layout height is set at 460dp. Use match_parent or wrap_content to fix that depending on your need.

Answer (score 0):

Use  android:layout_height="match_parent" in RelativeLayout.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem. The bottom ExpandableListView  it's scrollable, not the relatve layout.